# ionic application is not working in real device android 9 when it is downloaded from playstore

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ionic-framework

i  developed an application using ionic 4 and ionic 3. it is working fine when i installed it using ionic cordova run android, it also worked for all versions of android . but after uploading it to playstore the app is not working   on android 9 mobiles the request to the server is not happening

i tried to change my android platform to 8.0.0 but it doesn't work,

i also tried to add  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" for application selector  in AndroidManifest.xml,  the application is totally crashed when i tried to download it from playstore .

Comment: When you mean totally crashed, does it run in blank or not even run and close?

Have you been able to debug your application in --prod mode from localhost to see if it opens perfectly and you are not having problems with module loads in runtime?

Comment: It is not even running  for ionic 4 application where i used , android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in config.xml and for ionic 3 it is sucessfully  loaded and not connecting to server through http request.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Ionic CLI to latest version and then, run this command:

```
ionic cordova run android -l
```

After, you need update your config.xml with exact extract:

```
 <access origin="*" />
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
</edit-config>
```

And alternatively, add:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Comment: i tried  it but the app crashes when it is downloaded from google playstore